# filling grid SQLite Python

Tags: python, sqlite, gridview

I have a problem, i am trying to insert my SQLite DB information into wxpython grid and to use it with the max(rowid) function, I succeeded getting my last rowid but i couldnt find how to insert my data into the grid.

```
x = self.conn.execute("SELECT max(rowid) FROM tblPlayers")
print x.fetchone()
```

Comment: Could you post more code or the error info of your code?

Comment: i dont know, i can write the loop but not the insert code